# Groupby name in tcl list

Tags: list, group-by, tcl

I have a list like this

```
set a {CSCvi6:sunil CSCvi7:sunil CSCvi8:parames CSCvi87:sunil CSCvi878:sunil CSCvi89:arun CSCvi95:sunil CSCvj3:sunil CSCvj1:arun}
```

how can I display the list groupby names like

```
sunil:CSCvi6 CSCvi7 CSCvi87 CSCvi878 CSCvi95 CSCvj3
arun:CSCvi89 CSCvj1
parames :CSCvi8
```

I googled for  `groupby` in tcl but unfortunately I didn't found anything related like this. help meto do that

Comment: IMO, that task is a bit too 'narrow' for it to be a function in the standard library. When this happens, you usually have to try creating your own function. This is what the second part of Glenn's answer is about; he used [`proc`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl11.html) to create a new function (or procedure or command) called 'groupby` and he details the usage of this function with a couple of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate over the list and use a dict (or an array) to collect the groups:

```
set a {CSCvi6:sunil CSCvi7:sunil CSCvi8:parames CSCvi87:sunil CSCvi878:sunil CSCvi89:arun CSCvi95:sunil CSCvj3:sunil CSCvj1:arun}
set map [dict create]
foreach pair $a {
    lassign [split $pair :] value name
    dict lappend map $name $value
}
dict for {name values} $map {puts "$name: $values"}
```

```
sunil: CSCvi6 CSCvi7 CSCvi87 CSCvi878 CSCvi95 CSCvj3
parames: CSCvi8
arun: CSCvi89 CSCvj1
```

---

Taking a closer look, we can implement a `groupby` procedure that takes a list and creates a dictionary

```
proc groupby {varname lst grouping_code} {
    set result [dict create]
    upvar 1 $varname var
    foreach var $lst {
        set key [uplevel 1 $grouping_code]
        dict lappend result $key $var
    }
    return $result
}
```

An example, for a list of digits from 0 to 9, group by "modulo 3"

```
set groups [groupby n {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} {expr {$n % 3}}]
# {0 {0 3 6 9} 1 {1 4 7} 2 {2 5 8}}
```

Or, for your question

```
set a {CSCvi6:sunil CSCvi7:sunil CSCvi8:parames CSCvi87:sunil CSCvi878:sunil CSCvi89:arun CSCvi95:sunil CSCvj3:sunil CSCvj1:arun}

set groups [groupby elem $a {lindex [split $elem :] end}]
# {sunil {CSCvi6:sunil CSCvi7:sunil CSCvi87:sunil CSCvi878:sunil CSCvi95:sunil CSCvj3:sunil} parames CSCvi8:parames arun {CSCvi89:arun CSCvj1:arun}}
```

And to filter the names out of the groupings:

```
set groups [dict map {key value} $groups {lmap pair $value {lindex [split $pair :] 0}}]
# {sunil {CSCvi6 CSCvi7 CSCvi87 CSCvi878 CSCvi95 CSCvj3} parames CSCvi8 arun {CSCvi89 CSCvj1}}
```

I took some inspiration from [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for this implementation.

Comment: Thanks @glen. got the result.

Comment: I'm not clear with second Answer, I will go with first one only